# What's the commands of Cisco query bgp neighbor table, bgp table and router table?

Tags: cisco, router, bgp

In the AS router, I want to query its `bgp neighbor table`, `bgp table`, and `router table`.

what's the commands of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- BGP Route table `show ip bgp`
- BGP neighbor table  `show ip bgp neighbors`
- Route table `sh ip route`

Comment: What also might be handy is 'show ip route bgp', with that you can see the routes received via bgp only.